Can I do Two Months Internship in an EU country with French Visa (Non-EU Citizen)
I'm currently studying my MBA in France with a French long stay student Visa, which also authorizes me to work in France.
However, to complete my academic requirements I need to do a two-month internship to graduate. I currently have an opportunity to do this two-month internship in Greece which is part of the European Union. I would like to know whether I'm able to do the internship with my French visa or I need additional documentation and what are those required documents. I do not hold a European passport. (I am a Nigerian passport holder).

It usually depends on the details of the internship: Paid or unpaid, at an academic institution or a local business, whether it's mandatory for your studies or not. You probably need some sort of work permit but I don't really know as I don't know Greek law and practices. Your future employer will almost certainly need to be involved so you might ask them (if they don't have a clue, it's likely to be a problem either way). You shouldn't need an additional visa, permission to work is the main issue.

Any information as i am on the same case ?
